# I edit a product's details but they are not applying

Tags: product-edit

I try to edit a product's price or description details but when i click on "Save" or "Save and Continue", after i do it, the changes are not desplayed in the website, only they are changed in the admin panel. All things looks "enabled". How to make it work? The shop is made in 2012. Thank you for any answer!

Answer (score 0):

Did you flushed the cache?

You can flush the cache going to system > cache management.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/cache-storage-management

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I am a basic user, don't know what is that, I usually upload products and edit them. I googled these keywords, looks not for my level. Is it something I can do myself or it is a professionalist's thing to do?

Comment: You can flush the cache going to system > cache management. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/cache-storage-management